# How can I replace each group individually using Matcher?

Tags: java, regex

all the examples I found was for cases where people had some regex pattern
searched and needed to replaces all groups found with some  specific value, or with a known number of groups in the searched string.

But in my case I need to change each group depending on the values found, how can I change each changed result value?

This is what I have/tried:

```
 Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(DEFINITION_WITH_OR);
 Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
 StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
  while (matcher.find()){

  String ss = matcher.group();

    /*Some string manupilation*/

  // matcher.appendReplacement(sb, bestMatchedDefinition);
  // matcher.appendReplacement(sb,Matcher.quoteReplacement(ss));
  // s = s.replace(s.substring(matcher.start(),matcher.end()),ss);

}
```

What I wish to do is to iterate through all groups found, perform some actions on the group found, and edit only that group, the content & number of groups is not known prior to running.

All my tries so far either changed everything or not at all, any suggestions?

What I do with the string is split it by `|`, and get the shortest part, and remove braces so :
Example input string:
**Note**: the following input string is a simplification to show what my final outcome should be, the full string has a lot more annoying chars the I cleared using the `DEFINITION_WITH_OR` pattern

```
 a commissioned general officer in the United States Army,
 [[United States Marine Corps|Marine Corps]],
 or [[United States Air Force|Air Force]] superior to a lieutenant general.
 A general is equal in rank or grade to a four star admiral. In the US Army,
 a general is junior to a general of the army. In the US Marine Corps,
 a general is the highest rank of commissioned officer. In the US Air Force,
 a general is junior to a general of the air force.
```

Should output as:

```
 a commissioned general officer in the United States Army,
 Marine Corps,
 or Air Force superior to a lieutenant general.
 A general is equal in rank or grade to a four star admiral. In the US Army,
 a general is junior to a general of the army. In the US Marine Corps,
 a general is the highest rank of commissioned officer. In the US Air Force,
 a general is junior to a general of the air force.
```

mind the **Air Force** and **Marine Corps** bit.

Comment: You'll have a problem here since a `Matcher` is defined for one input string; if you update the string outside of the `Matcher`, it won't reflect changes. You have to create a new `Matcher` per string. (edit: in fact this is a lie, you can `.reset(CharSequence)`)

Comment: @fge it has one input string, but the pattern searched appears several times within that string, and I want those parts. This loop will give me all the groups found if I print them,

Comment: Yes, I understood that. Now, one question: are replacements also susceptible to be matched by the regex?

Comment: Can you post example of input end expected output, which would show problem you are facing? For now it seems that `appendReplacement` is correct way of doing things here. What is wrong with it?

Comment: I've added the input string, and the one you mentioned does not change anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, thanks to Joop's answer i've realized that I didn't add the following code :

```
matcher.appendTail(sb);
s = sb.toString();
```

After the while loop, and the line `matcher.appendReplacement(sb,Matcher.quoteReplacement(ss));` did do the trick.
For some reason also `matcher.appendReplacement(sb,ss);` worked, but much slower. If anyone knows why and could comment that'd be great.

Answer (score 2):

```
    String source = "a commissioned general officer in the United States Army, "
            + "[[United States Marine Corps|Marine Corps]], "
            + "or [[United States Air Force|Air Force]] superior to a lieutenant general.";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\[\\[(.*?)\\]\\]");
    Matcher m = pattern.matcher(source);
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    while (m.find()) {
        String[] terms = m.group(1).split("\\|");
        String shortestTerm = null;
        for (String term : terms) {
            if (shortestTerm == null || term.length() < shortestTerm.length()) {
                shortestTerm = term;
            }
        }
        m.appendReplacement(sb, shortestTerm);
    }
    m.appendTail(sb);
    String target = sb.toString();
    System.out.println(target);
```

Note the spurious backslashes. `".*?"` takes the shortest sequence matching.

Comment: +1 for better performance instead of `.*?` which uses backtracking you can write `[^]]*`.

Comment: This wouldn't work since this is not the whole string but a part of it  after the pattern search...my patter is very complex, the input string has alot more chars that I divide by to get the above input string

Comment: @eric.itzhak: still glad that it led you to your own solution. Accept that as answer, so the question no longer is tagged unanswered.

Comment: Sorry but I mean to mark my own as that's the solution to the problem, I can only tomorrow, thanks again for your help.

Comment: I meant too, to mark your own answer as solution. So no "sorry" needed.